# Create user from teamcity rest API

Tags: curl, teamcity, command-line-interface, teamcity-rest-api

rest api stated this command as to create user

```
curl -uadmin:admin -X POST 172.31.68.145:8111/app/rest/users
```

but it gives user list any suggestion how to create user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have not specified any post data for the request.

Let us take an example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:9090/api/login
```

This will perform a `POST` request on `http://localhost:9090/api/login` with the `POST` data:  `{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}` and header for this data is set to: `Content-Type: application/json`.